# Stefan-Sussman theorem

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, foliations

The Stefan-Sussmann theorem is a natural generalization of the Fröbenius theorem to singular smooth distributions. So, a singular smooth distribution is integrable if, and only if, it is generated for a family of invariant local vector fields.

Is there a generalization of this theorem to infinite dimensional manifolds?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think you need to specify the kind of infinite-dimensional manifolds you're interested in. Are they Banach manifolds? Frechet manifolds? Mapping spaces?